# Toggle CPU/GPU after(!) TensorFlow has been used once / Reset TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to compare runtimes of a TensorFlow graph on the GPU vs. CPU.

I know that I can enable/disable the GPU usage by changing the environment variable `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`. However, this change won't affect anything, if I already processed any TensorFlow computations before.

So I may need to *reset TensorFlow*. Neither `session.close()` nor `tf.reset_default_graph()` does help here though.

Finally, I know that I could wrap my code parts with something like

```
 with tf.Session() as sess:
      with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
```

, but this helps only locally and thereby requires me to change a lot of code parts. Instead, I'm looking for a global solution which does not require me to start a completely new Python session.

Any help is appreciated very much!

Comment: Could be an issue with an older driver version? https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1727 Otherwise if you're using recent versions of everything and Session.close doesn't free GPU resources, please file a bug (with a simple reproduction). Using Python's multiprocessing would be a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just updated my drivers as well as TensorFlow to the latest versions. The problem still exists though. I'm not sure whether this is considered to be a bug: `session.close()` _does_ free the GPU resources. However, next time I start a new session, the resources will be allocated again without paying attention to the latest value of the environment variable `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`, but using the original one. You may argue that this is the way it's supposed to be.. Using Python's multiprocessing may indeed be a good workaround.

Comment: Interesting. Not sure whether changes to `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` will affect anything after the process has been created (it's not a TensorFlow option, it's a CUDA option which determines which devices are visible to TensorFlow AFAIK).